# How flexible do some simple things on form validation success in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I have a form that contains two fields to upload files. I need to execute the following points:

- validate the form;
- move files to another directory;
- handle the moved files;
- return the result of handling.

Also I must return error messages if one of above points was failed. I am confused how to do that more flexible. I don't want to do all in controller.

I created form handler, form model, form type as in FOSUserBundle and added validation rules to form model in validation.yml. Form validation works fine.

I have an idea to use event dispatcher for this issue. After form validation I can notify event listeners.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

If you need to subscribe to the event because you need to perfom different actions (e.g. email the support, clean up trash, write down a failure log in the database), use event dispatcher. But if it's a simple thing like just display an error, it makes sense to use exceptions instead:

```
if ($form->isValid()) { 
    try { 
        $entity->handle(); 
    } catch (FileHandleException $e) { 
        ... 
    } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
        ... 
    }
}
```

Another option depends on what 'handle the moved files' is. If it's a part of validation (handle them to find that they are valid ssh keys, for example) and not business logic, then you can create a new validator and it'll become a part of form validation.

Comment: For instance, I need upload the files, move them to another directory, parse and do something with retrieved data. I think it is to many actions. I also thought about work with exception and return custom error codes. After that I thought that probably is sense to use for that event dispatcher... Thanks for the response.

Comment: I found an interesting article http://symfony.com/blog/using-the-symfony-event-system, but I am wondering how will I know that one of listeners has any errors? I mean how can I get the result of work of listeners?

Comment: @IgorTimoshenko that article is for symfony 1.x. I'd read [it](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html) instead. You'll have a service that moves and handles files. That service will have events like IO_ERROR, PROCESSING_ERROR (with better names of course ;)). Listeners will listen to those events and can do anything you need on a specific error. Not sure that the event dispatcher is what you need. What actions will be done on a error?

Comment: I noticed that the version is 1.x, but the principle is the same. I have a few services (the number of them can be large, the main principle that the next operation must be executed only if the previous had succeed). They are already defined as services and works fine. Also I want to have a chance to rollback previous executed operations on failure. I think it will be too many operations in one place so I would like to separate them and have a chance to handle and return errors for each failed operation. What should I use if not event dispatcher?